# How to use a general list of conditions in awk filtering?

Tags: bash, awk, geohashing

I use awk to filter geohash data in a csv file MYFILE, where the first column is the geohash.

```
cat $MYFILE | awk -F ',' '{if( $1 = "^f20" || $1 = "^f28") print $0 }' > extractedFile
```

The filtering is smooth and fast

But now the conditions f20 and f28 can be anything, given as input in a text file.

I have written this bash loop, but the speed is very low

```
ZONE=myZones.txt
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a ZONES < $ZONE
NZONES=${#ZONES[@]}

  cat $MYFILE | while read line
    do
        geohash=`echo $line | cut -d ',' -f 16`
        
        for zonehash in ${ZONES[@]}
        do
            if [[ $geohash == $zonehash* ]]
            then
                echo $line >> $MYOUTPUTFILE
            else
                continue
            fi
        done
    done
```

How can I adapt the awk command, so that the part noted XXXX be built accordingly to the input list of hashes?

```
cat $MYFILE | awk -F ',' '{if( XXXX ) print $0 }' > extractedFile
```

---

Edited after comments:

Given the following input files

MYFILE.csv
1,someData,f244qeb4qhz1
2,someData,f2hg1rqq6hh6
3,someData,f244qeb1z2nv

ZONES.txt
f24

awk 'NR==FNR{ZONES[$0]=$0; next} $1 in ZONES {print $0}' ZONES.txt MYFILE.csv

Comment: AHG! `cat $MYFILE | ` - *why would you do this?* `awk -F ',' '{if( $1 = "^f20" || $1 = "^f28") print $0 }' "$MYFILE" > extractedFile` does the same thing without spawning a `cat` and complicating the command. My pet peeves are itching! LOL!

Comment: On a separate note, `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a ZONES < "$ZONE"` is beautiful. Kudos for that one.

Comment: Yeah, in the original code the file was zipped, so I did gunzip -d -c $MYFILE |, when writing the example I simply replaced it by cat.

Comment: Regarding the bash read loop, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for why it's so slow and some other issues with it.  Also, if you copy/paste your shell script into http://shellcheck.net it'll tell you of additional issues you should know about for writing future scripts.

Comment: Regarding `Given the following input files` - Given the following input files ... what? It's not at all clear what we're supposed to make of the 3 lines below that text. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can best help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplified version of your `bash` logic in `awk` -

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ZONES[$0]=$0; next} $1 in ZONES' zones file
```

`zones` is the lookup table to load.
`NR==FNR` checks to see if the Number of the Record (overall) is the same as the Number of the Record from *this* File - in other words, if this is the first file.
If so, load it into the lookup table ZONES and move on.

If NR is not the same as FNR then it's not the first file any more, so the lookup table is loaded and we're processing data.
`$1 in ZONES` asks if field 1 is in the lookup table, and if it is, does whatever's in the curlies.

---

### #edit

Looking at your added data above, I made a slightly larger file with lines that match f20, f24, and f28.

`zones`:

```
$: cat zones
a
f20
b
f24
c
f28
```

`MYFILE.csv`:

```
$: cat MYFILE.csv
1,someData,f194qeb4qhz1 2,someData,f2hg1rqq6hh6 3,someData,f194qeb1z2nv
1,someData,f194qeb4qhz1 2,someData,f2hg1rqq6hh6 3,someData,f204qeb1z2nv
1,someData,f194qeb4qhz1 2,someData,f2hg1rqq6hh6 3,someData,f194qeb1z2nv
1,someData,f194qeb4qhz1 2,someData,f2hg1rqq6hh6 3,someData,f244qeb1z2nv
1,someData,f194qeb4qhz1 2,someData,f2hg1rqq6hh6 3,someData,f194qeb1z2nv
1,someData,f194qeb4qhz1 2,someData,f2hg1rqq6hh6 3,someData,f284qeb1z2nv
1,someData,f194qeb4qhz1 2,someData,f2hg1rqq6hh6 3,someData,f194qeb1z2nv


$: awk -F, 'NR==FNR{ZONES[$0]=$0; next} substr($7,0,3) in ZONES' zones MYFILE.csv
1,someData,f194qeb4qhz1 2,someData,f2hg1rqq6hh6 3,someData,f204qeb1z2nv
1,someData,f194qeb4qhz1 2,someData,f2hg1rqq6hh6 3,someData,f244qeb1z2nv
1,someData,f194qeb4qhz1 2,someData,f2hg1rqq6hh6 3,someData,f284qeb1z2nv
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Paul, I applied it to a reproducible example (see edition of my question), and it looks like I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `cut -d ',' -f 16`...but your example doesn't seem to have 16 fields. Your `awk` had `$1 = "^f20" || $1 = "^f28"` so I used $1, which is the first field. What part of your data is that supposed to match? The beginning of column 7 at `f244qeb1z2nv`?

Comment: yes, let's assume the 7th column are the geohashes, and the filter must ask, whether the element [, 7] starts with f24

Comment: Edited. Good luck. :)

Comment: You could just remove `{print $0}` since that's the default action given a true condition.

Comment: Done. Sometimes I put it anyway for readability/self-documentation in things someone else might have to maintain, but it's pointless in a throwaway.